# GridGain Hadoop Accelerator: Jobtracker not starting in the Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, gridgain

I'm using Hadoop Accelerator on Hadoop v1.1.2, I did the configuration that is given in the hadoop readme file.

While starting the cluster using start-all.sh, the jobtracker is not coming up. It throws the following error

FATAL mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/InvalidPathException

Comment: Are you using standard Apache Hadoop or any of the Cloudera, Hortonworks, or MapR distributions?

Comment: I'm using Apache Hadoop v1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, dude! The latest GridGain Hadoop Accelerator works only with Apache Hadoop 2.x versions according to [documentation](http://hadoop.gridgain.org/latest/Getting+Started).